# Simpler way to implement map function in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, computer-science

I know `List.map` uses recursion, I'm just wondering if there's a simpler way to implement map function without using recursion.
I know for `reverse`, I can simplify it into:

```
(* given *)
type 'a list =
  | []
  | (::) of 'a * 'a list
let nil : 'a list = []
let cons (hd : 'a) (tl : 'a list): 'a list = hd :: tl    

let reverse (ls : 'a list): 'a list =
      List.fold_left (Fun.flip cons) [] ls
```

Right now I'm thinking about using `@@`(the application operator), `%`(the function composition operator), and maybe `Fun.flip` or `List.fold_left` to do it, can anyone give me some hint about that?

I have tried the following, but OCaml raised an error about it.

```
List.fold_left (fun x -> f x) [] ls
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`List.fold_left` uses recursion, so presumably you're looking to avoid use of the `rec` keyword, rather than recursion at all.

You note in comments trying:

```
List.fold_left (fun x -> f x) [] ls
```

But the function passed to `List.fold_left` must take *two* arguments: the initial state, and the first element of the list. `Fun.flip cons` worked in your `reverse` function because it does take two arguments.

Note: `fun x -> f x` is the same as writing `f`.

If you initial state is a list, you need to do something to that list in the function you pass to `List.fold_left`, like adding the result of `f x` to the front of it. Since this builds the list backwards, you will need to reverse the result. This is where `@@` will come in handy.

```
let map f lst =
  List.(
    rev @@ fold_left (fun i x -> f x :: i) [] lst
  )
```